# How to sum duration time in the XSLT expressed in 'timespan' format

Tags: xml, xslt

In this code challenge I have to create an XSLT transformation that will sum iteration duration time for all TestResut nodes. In few words how long took the TestResults run.

```
    <TestResults>
        <TestResult>
            <Iteration duration="00:00:02.6312623" />
            <Iteration duration="00:01:03.5725194" />
            <Iteration duration="00:00:07.5725194" />
        </TestResult>
        <TestResult>
            <Iteration duration="00:00:04.6312623" />
            <Iteration duration="00:01:03.6777194" />
            <Iteration duration="00:02:07.5723194" />
        </TestResult>
    </TestResults>
```

Sum cannot be done directly on the TestResults/TestResult/Iteration/@duration xpath but instead convert in ticks that represent time is required here, and I am asking: what is the best practice to sum all durations avoiding at the same time multiple conversions?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
        xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
      <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

      <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="TotalDuration" select="sum(TestResults/TestResult/Iteration/@duration)"/>

        <Summary>
          <Duration>
            <xsl:value-of select="$TotalDuration"/>
          </Duration>
        </Summary>
      </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this XSLT 1.0 or 2.0? In 2.0 there is a lot of support for date/time arithmetic. In 1.0, look at the EXSLT date/time library.